# Using jQuery's Ajax to send string to HTTPServlet: Request is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send data back to my HTTPServlet on the press of a button.
At the end, my goal is to send back JSON data but for now, I'm just trying to send back a string.

When I click on the `saveThis`-button my server prints out "Empty" because my request data happens to be empty; What am I missing here?

My JavaScript:

```
$("#saveThis").click(function(e)
{
    $.post("clientserver", {
        "loadProds": 1,
        "test": "Hello"
    });
});
```

And my Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns= {"/clientserver"})
public class SayHelloServlet extends HttpServlet
{   
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        if(request.getParameter("saveThis") != null)
        {
            String json = request.getParameter("test");
            System.out.print(json);
        } else
        {
            System.out.print("Empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a POST request, so the data will be in the body of the request, not the parameters.

Try using:

```
request.getReader()
```

Or:

```
request.getInputStream()
```

To grab the request body in your Java code.